# вылетает куча ошибок в std::tie

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++11

Здравствуйте, есть такой код(UnicodeString - строка из c++ builder):

```
struct CTestParams {    
int TestDelay;  
double TglTest;
double DtTglTest;
int NumberVsi;
int View;
int NumberChannel;
std::string Name;
};

class CTest
{

public:
template<typename...Arg>
CTest(Arg&&...args)
{
    std::tuple<Arg...> tl { std::forward<Arg>(args)... };
    std::tie(testFolder, mimsFolder, resultFolder, nameTest, params) = tl;
}
CTest()
    : CTest_base(),
      mimsFolder(),
      nameTest(),
      resultFolder(),
      params()
{}
private:
UnicodeString testFolder;
UnicodeString mimsFolder;
UnicodeString nameTest;
UnicodeString resultFolder;
CTestParams params;
};

class CP
{
public:
void set_data(const CTest& elem)
{
    data = elem;
}
void set_dummy_test() {
    set_data(CTest {"...","...","...","...", CTestParams{} });
}
private:
CTest data;
};

int main() {
CP cp;
cp.set_dummy_test();
}
```

вылетает куча ошибок в строке с std::tie... в чем может быть дело тут?
ошибки:
 ctest.h(35): in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::tuple::operator=' requested here

[bcc64 Error] tuple(365): no viable overloaded '='

tuple(495): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const _Mybase' (aka 'const tuple<>') to 'const _Myt' (aka 'const tuple') for 1st argument;

компилятор c++builder x64

Comment: Кучу ошибок покажите.

Comment: вот, допустим:
 ctest.h(35): in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::tuple<System::UnicodeString &, System::UnicodeString &, System::UnicodeString &, System::UnicodeString &, CTestParams &>::operator=<testModel::CTest>' requested here

[bcc64 Error] tuple(365): no viable overloaded '='

  tuple(495): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const _Mybase' (aka 'const tuple<>') to 'const _Myt' (aka 'const tuple<System::UnicodeString &, System::UnicodeString &, System::UnicodeString &, CTestParams &>') for 1st argument;

Comment: Попробуйте при вызове `CTest` явно передавать `UnicodeString`, т.е. `CTest { UnicodeString("..."), ...` и т.д. А вообще, так ли нужен тут шаблонный конструктор?

Comment: как оказалось, на vs2013, например, компилируется нормально... это баг компилятора билдера... хотя там я заменил unicodestring на std::string... но у unicodestring нету явно заданного move-конструктора(по крайней мере не нашел), может дело в этом